# How to make Spring Kafka a long running service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

How do I keep my program running and producing messages? Whenever I try to run the code it automatically exits as long as the message is sent. I want to make it a long running service, to keep producing messages. I also want to apply that to the consumer class where in it won't end and just keep on reading messages.

This is what I'm working with. This is the KafkaApplication class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(KafkaApplication.class, args);
        TestBean testBean = context.getBean(TestBean.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            testBean.send("Hello World");
        }
        context.getBean(Listener.class).latch.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        context.close();
    }

    @Bean
    public TestBean test() {
        return new TestBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public Listener listener() {
        return new Listener();
    }

    public static class TestBean {
        @Autowired
        private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

        public void send(String message) {
            this.template.send(AppConfiguration.topic, message);
            this.template.flush();
        }

    }

    public static class Listener {

        private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(10);

        @KafkaListener(topics = AppConfiguration.topic, groupId = AppConfiguration.groupid)
        public void listen(@Payload String message, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition) {
            System.out.println("Received: " + message + " (partition: " + partition + ")");
            this.latch.countDown();
        }

    }

}
```

This is the configurations

```
public class KafkaConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory producerFactory(){
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, AppConfiguration.bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, "1");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "1000");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "5000");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG,"3");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG,"all");
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProperties());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, AppConfiguration.bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, AppConfiguration.groupid);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 15000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Comment: ... Put your producer code in a while loop and dont use latches?

Comment: *it automatically exits as long as the message is sent* So don't close the context.

Comment: How do I make it a long running service? Maybe a worker or something. Probably re run the producer automatically after the first run.

Comment: or how can I rerun the producer after a given amount of time?

Comment: You should use your OS scheduler (e.g. `cron`) to run at fixed intervals

Answer (score 0):

Don't close the application context in `main()`. The listener uses a non-daemon thread by default so the JVM will keep running, even after the main thread exits.

Stopping the context will stop the listener (and its thread).